# Spark : Data processing using Spark for large number of files says SocketException : Read timed out

Tags: amazon-s3, mapreduce, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pyspark

I am running Spark in standalone mode on 2 machines which have these configs

1. 500gb memory, 4 cores, 7.5 RAM
2. 250gb memory, 8 cores, 15 RAM

I have created a master and a slave on 8core machine, giving 7 cores to worker. I have created another slave on 4core machine with 3 worker cores. The UI shows 13.7 and 6.5 G usable RAM for 8core and 4core respectively.

Now on this I have to process an aggregate of user ratings over a period of 15 days. I am trying to do this using Pyspark
This data is stored in hourwise files in day-wise directories in an s3 bucket, every file must be around 100MB eg

*s3://some_bucket/2015-04/2015-04-09/data_files_hour1*

I am reading the files like this

```
a = sc.textFile(files, 15).coalesce(7*sc.defaultParallelism) #to restrict partitions
```

where files is a string of this form *'s3://some_bucket/2015-04/2015-04-09/*,s3://some_bucket/2015-04/2015-04-09/*'*

Then I do a series of maps and filters and persist the result

```
a.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

Then I need to do a reduceByKey to get an aggregate score over the span of days.

```
b = a.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y).map(aggregate)
b.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

Then I need to make a redis call for the actual terms for the items the user has rated, so I call  mapPartitions like this

```
final_scores = b.mapPartitions(get_tags)
```

*get_tags* function creates a redis connection each time of invocation and calls redis and yield a *(user, item, rate)* tuple
(The redis hash is stored in the 4core)

I have tweaked the settings for SparkConf to be at

```
conf = (SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME).setMaster(master)
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "5g")
        .set("spark.akka.timeout", "10000")
        .set("spark.akka.frameSize", "1000")
        .set("spark.task.cpus", "5")
        .set("spark.cores.max", "10")
        .set("spark.serializer",      "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
        .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb", "10")
        .set("spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles", "True")
        .set("spark.files.fetchTimeout", "500")
        .set("spark.task.maxFailures", "5"))
```

I run the job with driver-memory of 2g in client mode, since cluster mode doesn't seem to be supported here.
The above process takes a long time for 2 days' of data (around 2.5hours) and completely gives up on 14 days'.

What needs to improve here?

1. Is this infrastructure insufficient in terms of RAM and cores (This is offline and can take hours, but it has got to finish in 5 hours or so)
2. Should I increase/decrease the number of partitions?
3. Redis could be slowing the system, but the number of keys is just too huge to make a one time call.
4. I am not sure where the task is failing, in reading the files or in reducing.
5. Should I not use Python given better Spark APIs in Scala, will that help with efficiency as well?

This is the exception trace

```
Lost task 4.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 11, <node>): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:554)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:509)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:891)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:200)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:174)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(EntityUtils.java:88)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.releaseConnection(HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.java:102)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.close(HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.seek(NativeS3FileSystem.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream.seek(BufferedFSInputStream.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(CoalescedRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(CoalescedRDD.scala:92)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1617)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:205)
```

I could really use some help, thanks in advance

Here is what my main code looks like

`def main(sc):
    f=get_files()
    a=sc.textFile(f, 15)
        .coalesce(7*sc.defaultParallelism)
        .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
        .filter(len(line)>0)
        .map(lambda line: (line[18], line[2], line[13], line[15])).map(scoring)
        .map(lambda line: ((line[0], line[1]), line[2])).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
    b=a.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y).map(aggregate)
    b.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
    c=taggings.mapPartitions(get_tags)
    c.saveAsTextFile("f")
    a.unpersist()
    b.unpersist()`

The get_tags function is

```
def get_tags(partition):
 rh = redis.Redis(host=settings['REDIS_HOST'], port=settings['REDIS_PORT'], db=0)
 for element in partition:
    user = element[0]
    song = element[1]
    rating = element[2]
    tags = rh.hget(settings['REDIS_HASH'], song)
    if tags:
        tags = json.loads(tags)
    else:
        tags = scrape(song, rh)
    if tags:
        for tag in tags:
            yield (user, tag, rating)
```

The get_files function is as:

```
def get_files():
 paths = get_path_from_dates(DAYS)
 base_path = 's3n://acc_key:sec_key@bucket/'
 files = list()
 for path in paths:
    fle = base_path+path+'/file_format.*'
    files.append(fle)
 return ','.join(files)
```

The get_path_from_dates(DAYS) is

```
def get_path_from_dates(last):
 days = list()
 t = 0
 while t <= last:
    d = today - timedelta(days=t)
    path = d.strftime('%Y-%m')+'/'+d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    days.append(path)
    t += 1
 return days
```

Comment: There are a lot of details in this question. I suggest you break this into a few separate questions. For example, you may choose one question to help you solve the exception and another to help with performance.

Comment: Thanks , I agree, but I have been myself unable to drill down to the cause  and hence the solution. Ergo I am providing the whole context so that anybody who is interested in the question gets the whole context and can answer accordingly. It may look like a performance tuning code review, but I badly need it :(

Comment: I appreciate your situation. I'll try to help as much as I can. 
Regarding performance issues, start with a single input split (I assume that is a single 100MB file). Can you tune your job running locally on your machine (i.e., remove the AWS component)? Is your code efficient? Usually that's where the greatest inefficiencies are. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: @Myles Baker, PFA some parts of MR job

Comment: For an optimization, can I broadcast the redis-connection ?

Comment: With one machine locally, the reduceByKey (Stage 0) finished in 8s, but Stage 1 is taking a good amount of time still, though no tasks failed, so a new prolem as arisen about how to optimise for redis calls

Answer (score 0):

As a small optimization, I have created two separate tasks, one to read from s3 and get additive sum, second to read transformations from redis. The first tasks has high number of partitions since there are around 2300 files to read. The second one has much lesser number of partitions to prevent redis connection latency, and there is only one file to read which is on the EC2 cluster itself. This is only partial, still looking for suggestions to improve ...

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar usecase: doing `coalesce` on a RDD with 300,000+ partitions. The difference is that I was using s3a(`SocketTimeoutException` from `S3AFileSystem.waitAysncCopy`). Finally the issue was resolved by setting a larger `fs.s3a.connection.timeout`(Hadoop's `core-site.xml`). Hopefully you can get a clue.